# Is it possible to use different entity for JoinColumn annotation? (Conditional JoinColumn)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

My scenario is this:
I have 2 tables, first table for daily data (which then will be moved to the second table) let's call it Table **Daily_Jobs**, and second table for housekeeping data (storage for daily_jobs) let's call it Table **Housekeeping_Jobs**.
Then i have these table (let's call it **hold_monitoring_jobs**) which takes the daily jobs data for joining the result.

Here is the entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOLD_MONITORING_JOBS")
@Getter
@Setter
public class HoldMonitoringJobs {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="JOBS_ID")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private DailyJobs jobs;

    private String holdStatus;

    private Date startDateHold;

    private Date expiryDateHold;

    private Date releaseDateHold;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DAILY_JOBS")
@Setter
@Getter
public class DailyJobs implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private Date businessDate;

    private Date transactionDate;

    private String transactionCode;

    private String jobsDescription;

    private String userIdHandler;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSEKEEPING_JOBS")
@Setter
@Getter
public class HousekeepingJobs implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private String jobsId;

    private Date businessDate;

    private Date transactionDate;

    private String transactionCode;

    private String jobsDescription;

    private String userIdHandler;
}
```

My question is, suppose that there is a **job** being **hold** (which then created new entry record HoldMonitoringJob), and then the **job** is being moved at the end of the day to table **HousekeepingJobs**, how can i get these **HoldMonitoringJobs** to join the table *conditionally* to **HousekeepingJobs** if the record isn't available anymore in the table **DailyJobs**?

Something like:

```
if DailyJobs found:
    join with table DailyJobs by referring to the column id;
else:
    join with table HousekeepingJobs by referring to the column jobsId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing. There is no way to do conditional joins in SQL and thus also not in HQL, but you can just join data and return what you want based on your conditional logic. You would need something like the following:

```
select m, j, h
from HoldMonitoringJobs m
left join m.jobs j
left join HousekeepingJobs h on h.jobsId = coalesce(j.id, m.jobs.id)
```